# Perceptron Algorithm Confusion

Tags: python, algorithm, perceptron

I have this problem that I'm trying to solve:

```
def phi(x):
    # DO NOTHING ON THIS FUNCTION
    if x<=0:
        return -1.0
    else:
        return 1.0
    
phi = np.vectorize(phi)
```

This is where I need to implement the function:

```
def predictOne(x, w):
    z =  
    return phi(z)
```

But when I try to use my formula but with my input code:

```
def predictOne(x, w):
    z =  0 + x * w
    return phi(z)
```

And run my asserts:

```
assert predictOne(np.array([0.0,0.0]) , np.array([0.1,3.2,7.4])) == 1.0
assert predictOne(np.array([0.0,0.0]), np.array([-0.1,3.2,7.4])) == -1.0
assert predictOne(np.array([0.3,-0.7]), np.array([0.1,3.2,7.4])) == -1.0
assert predictOne(np.array([0.3,0.7]), np.array([0.1,3.2,7.4])) == 1.0
```

I get an (operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)

Apparently, the assertions are correct so I'm doing somethin wrong in my predictOne function. Can anyone help?

Comment: What did you intend to be the meaning of multiplying a 2-element array with a 3-element array?

Comment: And what did you hope to achieve by adding 0?

Comment: it's based off the perceptron algorithm function (mathematics)

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the formula:

```
def predictOne(x, w):
    z = w[0] + np.sum(x * w[1:])
    return phi(z)
```

- `w[0]` is bias. Bias of zero, as pointed out by @mkrieger, doesn't make a lot of sense.
- perceptron essentially calculates weighted sum of inputs, so the result should be summed up.

Comment: I guess cause the bias is a constant. I wasn't really sure how to handle that in the formula.